# Join in Laravel's Eloquent

Tags: database, laravel, select, join, eloquent

I have a visit Model and I'm getting the data I want like that:

```
$app_visits = Visit::select([
    'start',
    'end',
    'machine_name'
])->where('user_id', $chosen_id)->get();
```

But I want to add points for every visit. Every visit has an interaction (but there's no visit_id (because of other system I cannot add it).

Last developer left it like that:

```
$interactions = Interaction::where([
    'machine_name' => $app_visit->machine_name,
])->whereBetween('date', [$app_visit->start, $app_visit->end])->get();

$points = 0;
foreach ($interactions as $interaction) {
    $points +=  (int)$interaction->app_stage;
}
$app_visits[$key]['points'] = $points
```

But I really don't like it as it's slow and messy. I wanted to just add 'points' sum to the first query, to touch database only once.

@edit as someone asked for database structure:

visit:

```
|id | start | end | machine_name | user_id
```

inteaction:

```
|id | time | machine_name |  points
```

Comment: post your database structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a few things in eloquent. Probably the most useful for this case, is the `select(DB::raw(sql...))` as you will have to add a bit of raw sql to retrieve a count.

For example:

```
return $query
    ->join(...)
    ->where(...)
    ->select(DB::raw(
        COUNT(DISTINCT res.id) AS count'
    ))
    ->groupBy(...);
```

Failing that, I'd just replace the eloquent with raw sql. We've had to do that a fair bit, as our data sets are massive, and eloquent model building has proven a little slow.

**Update** as you've added structure. Why not just add a relation to Interaction, based upon `machine_name` (or even a custom method using raw sql that calculates the points), and use: `Visits::with('interaction.visitPoints')->...blah` ?

Comment: well I will try that now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at DB instead of Eloquent:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

For more complex and efficient queries.
There is also a possibility to use raw SQL with this facade.